# Proving $(f \circ g)(n) \in O( (g \circ f)(n) ) $ given $f$ and $g$ are increasing functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I look at this question and determine that, by intuitive, this results to proving

$f(n) \in O(f^{-1}(n))$ for $f$ and $f^{-1}$ being increasing functions since $(f \circ g)(n)$ is the inverse of $(g \circ f)(n) $

If they are both increasing functions, by properties of inverse functions, there must be an intersection point since $f^{-1}$ has inverse coordinates from $f$.

Thus, since there it is an intersection point for the two functions we can conclude that $f(n) \notin O(f^{-1}(n))$ and, hence, $(f  \circ g)(n) \notin O( (g \circ f)(n) ) $ for $\forall n \in N.$

My concern: I have a feeling my proof is too simple. If I am missing something or forgot something please feel free to comment below.

Comment: $f \circ g$ is not the inverse of  $g \circ f$ :)

Comment: If $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, then $f(n)=O(f^{-1}(n))$ is true for the trivial reason that the only increasing function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ that has an inverse all is the identity!

Comment: What does having an intersection point have to do with whether this is $O$ of that?

Comment: Consider $f(n)=2^n$, $g(n)=2n$...

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Perhaps, but is it true that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$? I would think, rather, that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Then it's true for the even more trivial reason that there is no invertible function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ at all.

Comment: @Henning: Right, of course. I think Antoine's comment is appropo. The inverse of $g\circ f$ is $f^{-1}\circ g^{-1}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it would prove that there is no clear upper bound $\forall n \in N$

Comment: @MauriceMaurice Huh??? Let $f(n)=n$. Then $f$ and $f^{-1}$ have plenty of intersection points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is one counter-example, which David C. Ullrich has provided in the comments. I'll "answer-ify" his comment. Let 
\begin{align*}
f(n)&=2^n\\
g(n)&=2n.
\end{align*}
Then both functions are increasing. However, $(f\circ g)(n)=2^{2n}$ is not Big O of $(g\circ f)(n)=2\cdot 2^n,$ as the former increases much faster than the latter.